# How to draw custom views on top and bottom of the candle in candlestick chart

Tags: ios, swift, charts, candlestick-chart, candlesticks

I am using the iOS [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library for the candlestick chart, I not able to find any way to draw custom views that is a triangle as shown in the image library.

I want to show the triangle(view) on the top and bottom of the candle based on the flag.

If this is not possible in [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library please let me know the alternate library where I can achieve this.

[CandleSitckChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u12vi.png)

{

```
    chartView.delegate = self
    
    chartView.chartDescription?.enabled = true
    chartView.drawBordersEnabled = false
    chartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
    
    chartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = .white
    chartView.rightAxis.labelTextColor = .white
    
    chartView.dragEnabled = true
    chartView.setScaleEnabled(true)
    chartView.pinchZoomEnabled = true
    chartView.drawMarkers = true
    
    chartView.legend.enabled = false

    chartView.leftAxis.enabled = false
    
    chartView.leftAxis.spaceTop = 0.3
    chartView.leftAxis.spaceBottom = 0.3
    chartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
    chartView.rightAxis.enabled = true
    chartView.rightAxis.axisLineColor = .primaryBlue
    chartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
    
    let candleResponse = MasterData.shared.candleResponse
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    
    let dates = candleResponse
        .map { Date(timeIntervalSince1970: ($0.first ?? 0)/1000) }
        .map { dateFormatter.string(from: $0) }
    
    chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: dates)
    chartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    
    
    let yVals1 = (0..<candleResponse.count).map { (i) -> CandleChartDataEntry in
        return CandleChartDataEntry(x: Double(i),
                             shadowH: candleResponse[i][2],
                             shadowL: candleResponse[i][3],
                             open: candleResponse[i][1],
                             close: candleResponse[i][4])
    }
   
    let set1 = CandleChartDataSet(entries: yVals1)
    set1.setDrawHighlightIndicators(true)
    set1.drawVerticalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = true
    set1.drawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = true

    set1.axisDependency = .right
    set1.setColor(UIColor(white: 80/255, alpha: 1))
    set1.drawIconsEnabled = true
    set1.shadowColor = .darkGray
    set1.shadowWidth = 0.7
    set1.decreasingColor = .red
    set1.decreasingFilled = true
    set1.increasingColor = UIColor(red: 122/255, green: 242/255, blue: 84/255, alpha: 1)
    set1.increasingFilled = true
    set1.neutralColor = .blue

    let data = CandleChartData(dataSet: set1)
    data.setDrawValues(false)
    chartView.data = data
}
```

Comment: Hi Mehul - welcome to Stack. Post your code so we can take a look.

Comment: Can you please look at the image?
I want to know how to draw that kind of view.
@JohnnyRockex

Comment: You can't do it from this level - you'll need to drop down into lower code to adapt the draw function. What you're asking for isn't too complex though - you could draw your own instead of using a library.

Comment: @JohnnyRockex can you please provide some kind of reference or guidance so that I can figure it out how to do that.